# How to call a public function of a C++ object in lldb command line?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm trying to test the result of a C++ function call. The function is public and the debugger is inside a call where the object is a member. Here is the class interface:

```
class NumerialDispersion {
    MeshSystem mesh;

    vector<double> b_k;
    vector<double> c_k;


public:
    void setupMeshSystem();
    void setUpAnalysis();
    void calculateK();
};
```

I Need to test a function that I have declared inside MeshSystem. The interface of MeshSystem class is as follows:

```
class MeshSystem {

    Element mainMeshElement;


public:
    MeshSystem(Element element, double tStep);


    double get_b_k(uint index);

};
```

I need to execute the function get_b_k() in lldb with different values of index. I am using Xcode 4.6 user Mountain Lion.

Does lldb supports such expressions? If yes, could any one help me?

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just calling it? E.g. `mesh.get_b_k(some_index)`?

Comment: I tried using expr mesh.get_b_k(some_index). But it didn't work. 

I tried accessing the object using this pointer as this->mesh. If I write expr this->mesh it shows all the member variables. 

But trying with expr this->mesh.get_b_k(i) or expr this->mesh->get_b_k(i) does not work.

Is there any specific command for executing a class function?

Comment: what does lldb respond with when doing this?

Answer (score 2):

either type

```
p mesh.get_b_k(1)
```

or

```
expr -- mesh.get_b_k(1)
```

Note that the function may be not present in a target at all, that is not used and its body just was not compiled. In this case use it in some fake way, or make exportable (annotate with **attribute** ((visibility ("default"))) )